# Rearranging disk partitions

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, gparted

**Updated Description:** I'm trying to set up a dual boot system on an HP Pavilion laptop.  In the past I've probably set up six or seven dual-boot systems and never had any difficulty.  The process was always straightforward and I usually even had the choice of whether to use the Windows boot-manager or Grub, since either would work.

But this time was different; I can't get the computer to boot into grub/ubuntu directly on power-up. This behavior seems to be coming from the underlying HP software, since pressing F9 on bootup gives me a menu where I can select which system to boot.  That menu, however, does not offer any way to change the sequence of its entries.

Perhaps the history of this particular laptop is relevant; it was given to me by a friend, and I never removed the HP recovery partition, thinking that it wouldn't be necessary.  I trashed the existing old Windows 7 installation and installed Kubuntu as the only system on the machine.  That was fine until I changed my mind about Windows and tried to install it again. That's how I ended up in the situation where there was a perfectly fine Kubuntu, a perfectly fine Windows, but no way to get grub to take control initially.  Once I got grub started, I could run either Kubuntu or Windows -- they were both on grub's menu.

I might be able to solve the problem by reordering the partitions using **gparted** from a live system on a memory stick, but I don't know if it's sufficient to just change the numbers (doable with **fdisk**) or if the partitions actually have to be moved within the physical disk.  The danger, of course, is that any change of this nature can render the system unbootable. Is there a way to do this safely?

Comment: To change the order in your BIOS settings you don't enter in the boot selection menu. Generally speaking, the keys to enter the settings are F2 or Del, but not necessarelly are those.

Comment: When the computer starts, generally you will have a brief screen that tells you wich key you have to press to enter  the settings, where you can change the boot order.

Comment: It’s nothing to do with the order of the partitions. Can you get Ubuntu to boot at all. If so how? I saw an EFI partition on an earlier post. Did you follow a guide for installing Ubuntu in a dual boot UEFI scenario? Windows and Ubuntu will not dual boot unless they are running in the same mode. That is both UEFI or both legacy.

Comment: Back up, verify the backup files match the files they came from, and then do it again on different media. Disk partition operations lose more data than even _rm -rf *_ https://github.com/sindresorhus/guides/blob/master/how-not-to-rm-yourself.md

Comment: Try pressing the Esc key after booting.

Comment: Dual Boot advice:

I suggest you read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power-on_self-test , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BIOS , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UEFI . One will have the Answer. Read the others to understand that one.

Comment: I was having so much trouble because I was starting from a bad initial state.  I solved my dual-boot problem the dramatic way: I repartitioned the disk, thus emptying it entirely, and easily reinstalled Windows and then Kubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

usually Grub will display, if you've removed Windows, so there is no other player in the game. 
But: (there is always a but ;-) if grub has a hidden timeout -you won't see it. It will just start an you couldn't change the to the image you'd like to start. Depending on your grub version you may alter the line in /etc/default/grub:

```
GRUB_TIMEOUT=5
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=menu
```

(this is valid for grub 2.04 - currently I'm running not ubuntu, so you version might be different)
A timeout of ‘0’ means to boot the default entry immediately without displaying the menu.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by repartitioning the disk, thus wiping it entirely, and reinstalling Windows and then Kubuntu.